# What are good sources of StackExchange.com metrics?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Is this report of Stack Exchange usage accurate?

http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com

Are there better sources of the data?

Answer (score 2):

Alexa is quite reliable (at least, I haven't heard complaints about it). Stack Exchange has a dedicated integration with [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackexchange.com?qcLocale=en_US) which may provide better data (depending on what you're looking for).

Another source of information, when you have 25,000 reputation on a site, are the [site analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) which is basically a lite version of Google Analytics.